# Submit an HTML form without having a submit button?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Can I submit a html `<form>` with `<div>` instead of `<input type="submit">` ?

Like this:

```
<form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
  <textarea name="reply">text</textarea>
</form>

<div>Submit the form by clicking this</div>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The method you can use to submit a specific form is the following:

```js
// Grab the form element and manually trigger the 'submit' method on it:
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

So in your example, you can add a click event handler on any element you like and trigger the form's submit method through that:

```html
<form method="post" id="myForm">
  <textarea name="reply">text</textarea>
</form>

<div class="submit">Submit the form by clicking this</div>
```

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
document.querySelector(".submit").addEventListener("click", function(){

  myForm.submit();

});
```

And if you want to do it jQuery style (which **I do not recommend for such a simple task**);

```js
$("#myForm").submit();
```

In its full form:

```js
const myForm = $("#myForm");
$(".submit").click(function(){

  myForm.submit();

});
```

---

**References:**

- The [submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) method of HTML Form elements (native `JavaScript API`)
- The `jQuery` [submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) API

Comment: This is the JavaScript-only way.  It's even simpler with jQuery.

Comment: why does everybody nowadays use for the simplest tasks jquery? jQuery will add like 500 CPU instructions on top of this solution. If you can do something straightforward, why not just do it?

Comment: @japrescott The `submit` method in jQuery isn't very expensive. It basically just calls the native Javascript function. I'm not sure why you're so adamant about not using jQuery in this case.

Comment: @japrescott, because the OP tagged his question with jQuery!

Comment: @PeterOlson Its not about the submit method, its about selecting an element that could be fetched the directest way even possible in javascript! Its not gonna slowdown anything using jQuery in this case, but if you have 100ds of these cases within your application, at some point, it will!

Comment: I would say the jQuery way is a little cleaner, but NOT simpler. They are both one liners. jQuery would be overkill for this task. :)

Comment: Not specific to this question but you SHOULD actually use jquery for even simple tasks because it saves you from behavioural differences of browsers. By using Jquery you are sure that what you meant will happen without having to take care of each browser scenario.

Comment: @1.44mb to a certain point you are correct. But then again, you are programming javascript, not jquery. I know many people that have no clue what they are doing and use jquery everywhere and in a bad way because they never learnt how to develop in javascript and realize what jquery does internally. I always teach javascript first, show them the pain and then offer jquery as the salvation depending which audience they are aiming at (<=IE8 or >=IE9). In my opinion, if you are aiming at modern browsers, there is no need for jquery at all. zepto if you are really lazy..

Comment: @Simone in that case you can still rely on `document.forms[0].submit()`. There is no need for jQuery

Comment: The silly discussion of JQuery v JS is irrelevant if the question asks for jquery. And  people making all sorts of statements about JS better this and that are being utterly fanatical. In the long run its what the customer gets NOT how its done. Ive seen utterly crap code get published in top shelf AAA games, and amazing optimised code get thrown away. Forget the sill evangelism people - its outcomes and solutions that count. Not what pet favourite thing you like this week.

Comment: ya. that's the .submit() is the answer for this!

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's fairly simple. Just use the [`submit`<sup>[jQuery docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) method inside of a `click` handler function.

```
$("#myDiv").click(function() {
 $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

If you prefer, you can do it with vanilla Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Bind the div click event.

`$("div").click(function(){ $("form#myForm").submit(); });`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#myDiv').click(function() {  
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery:

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to unnecessarily depend on JavaScript, then you could…

```
jQuery('div').click(function () { jQuery('form').submit(); });
```

… however, you should use semantic HTML that works without JS being present. So use a real submit button and apply CSS to make it look the way you want.

Comment: Just hitting the "enter" key will also submit a form without a button or JavaScript.

Comment: @Sparky672 — Since the form only has a textarea in it … no it won't.

Comment: Unfortunately, submit buttons are limited in how they can be styled. They might not be flexible enough for his purposes.

Comment: @PeterOlson `<button>` remains a viable alternative then.

Comment: @Quentin,  I disagree.  I just created a simple search box (without a button) that submits upon "Enter" (without JS) and it works in all the major browsers.

Comment: Sorry Quentin, you are correct.  I mistakenly thought of _"text box"_ when you said _"text area"_.

Answer (score 2):

For better semantics and graceful degradation, I suggest you do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form input[type="submit"]').replaceWith('<div class="submit">Submit the form by clicking this</div>'); // replace submit button with div

    $('.submit').live('click', function() {  
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

This way, your form remains usable for clients without JS.

That being said: Just style your input to look the way you want it to with CSS ;)

Comment: Pretty simple jquery plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/yckart/3b4yzj8h/ We could optimize it by iterating over each submit-input, to replace each with an individual.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#submitDiv').click(function() {
        $('#myForm').submit();
     });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
<textarea name="reply">text</textarea>
</form>

<div id="submitDiv">Submit the form by clicking this</div>
```

Comment: This code will not work currently because it of cross site-forgery,

Answer (score 0):

Only by using JavaScript, typically you'd use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and tie the click event of the div to the submit event of the form.

See: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

The example there even demonstrates this exact scenario.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just style a button to look like a regular div? :)

```
button{
    border:none;
    background:none;
    padding:0;
    text-align:left; 
}
```

Comment: Because the submit button has to be outside the form.

Comment: @RiMMER ah, missed that sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['text']) && !empty($_POST['text']))
{
   echo $text_val = $_POST['text'];
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <form method="post" action="Enter your action">
        <p><label>Enter your Text : </label>
        <input type="text" name="text" id="text" onmouseover="this.form.submit();"></input>
        </p>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```